# Proof-verification for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot \binom nk$ for a fixed $k\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, binomial-coefficients

> Proof-verification for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot \binom nk$ for a fixed $k\in \mathbb{N}$

so that's how I solved it:$$\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot \binom nk=\frac{n!}{2^n \cdot k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot k! \cdot \ldots \cdot (n-k+1)\cdot (n-k)! }{2^n \cdot k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot  (n-k+1)}{2^n} \overset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0$$

since we know that exponential growth is way faster than polynomial growth...

Comment: The proof is not totally correct because : $$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{k!} $$ In the last line, you have : $$\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{k}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{n^k}{2^n k!}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 $$

Comment: @Mishikumo2019 The proof is incorrect, as the last line is not equal to the first line.

Comment: How come? I figured that eventually we will get $k!$ in the numerator, I didn't really know how to put it formally though.

Comment: A related question: [Determine $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{{n} \choose {\frac{n}{2}}}\frac{1}{2^n}$, where each $n$ is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288614)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a factor $k!$ in your last expression.
Also, you could make that last sentence more explicit by noting that the sequence is nonnegative and
$$\frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot  (n-k-1)}{2^n k!}\leq\frac{n^k}{2^n k!}\leq\frac{n^k}{2^n}$$

Comment: I figured that eventually we will get $k!$ in the numerator, I didn't really know how to put it formally though. (?)

Comment: What do you mean by 'get $k!$' in the numerator? Of course the numerator is divisible by $k!$ because $\tbinom{n}{k}$ is an integer.

Comment: So, since $k$ is fixed, consider $3!$. We know that as $n\to \infty$, we will have $3!$ in the numerator eventually ...

Comment: That does not make any clearer to me what you mean by 'have $3!$' in the numerator.  Either way, you cannot simply omit the factor $k!$ and put an equals sign. The two expressions are not equal.

Answer (score 3):

Noting that, for $n\ge k$,
$$ 2^n=(1+1)^n\ge \binom{n+1}{k+1}=\binom{n}{k}\frac{n+1}{k+1} $$
one has
$$ 0\le \frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{k}\le\frac{k+1}{n+1} $$
which implies
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{k}=0.$$

Comment: Crème de la crème! :)

Comment: I think you need $n\geq 2k$ for the first inequality to hold.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the proof is correct, but the proof is not rigorous because the factors of $\binom nk$ have been handled haphazardly. A more rigorous approach is to notice that since $k$ is fixed, $\binom nk$ is a $k$th degree polynomial (all but the first $k$ factors in $n!$ are removed by the division by $(n-k)!$, while $k$ is a fixed constant) and then to use the fact of exponential functions growing faster than all fixed-order polynomial functions, as before.