# Alternative proof of an intereting identity of Catalan's Numbers and central binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, number-theory, catalan-numbers

Some time ago i got from Polya's Urn Scheme that for the n-th Catalan number $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ and the central binomial coefficient takes place the identity
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\frac{C_{n+k}}{4^n} = 2\binom{2k}{k}$$

I'm looking for a non-probabilistic proof of that result.

Comment: That equation makes no sense. The left side is a function of $n$; the right side is a function of $k$. [Also, what's CBC? To me, that's the Canadian Broadcasting Corporation.]

Comment: The verb in this context is "to prove", not "to proof".

Comment: Fixed, thanks, that is the effect of the 'very first time'

Comment: If there is a generating functions proof, you'd probably want to show that $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\tfrac{C_{n+k}}{4^n}x^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}2\binom{2k}{k}x^k$. The right side is $\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$. The left side is obviously tougher, but swapping the order of the summation, or summing the terms in a different order would be my first guess.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 i already tried that and unfortunately i got nothing, thanks anyway

Comment: You don't want a probability answer, but how about bijective enumeration? If you accepted probability and had a copy of Feller available, probability of SRW to not return to 0 before time $2n$ calculated by partitioning-and-summing over the first time to return to 0: being time $2n$, $2n+2$, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Catalan numbers generating function
power series multiplied by $x$ is
$$ \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^{n+1}. \tag{1} $$
Substitute $\,y\,$ for $\,x\,$ and subtract both equations to get
$$ \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4y}}2- \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}2 =
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n (y^{n+1}-x^{n+1}). \tag{2} $$
Divide both sides by $\,y-x\,$ and express
$\,\frac{y^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{y-x}\,$ as a sum to get
$$ \frac{\sqrt{1-4x}-\sqrt{1-4y}}{2(y-x)} = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \frac{y^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{y-x} = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\sum_{m=0}^n y^m x^{n-m}. \tag{3} $$
Simplify the left side and change summation indices on the right
to get
$$ \frac2{\sqrt{1-4y}+\sqrt{1-4x}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty
C_{n+k}\,y^n x^k. \tag{4}$$
Substitute $\,y=\frac14\,$ and expand $\,\frac2{\sqrt{1-4x}}\,$
with binomial coefficients to get
$$ \frac2{\sqrt{1-4x}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2\binom{2k}{k}x^k =
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{C_{n+k}}{4^n} x^k. \tag{5}$$
Finally, equate corresponding coefficients of $\,x^k\,$ to get
$$ 2\binom{2k}{k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{C_{n+k}}{4^n}. \tag{6} $$

Comment: Thanks man, i was looking specially for an answer using generating functions.

Answer (score 7):

We want to show
$$
\frac{2}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\frac{C_{n+k}}{4^{n+k}}= \sum_{n = k}^\infty\frac{C_{n}}{4^{n}}.
\tag{1}$$

Notice the following property (which can be verified for example by writing out the factorials, see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879053/290240)):
$$
\frac{C_n}{4^n}=2\left[\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}-\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}\right].
$$
Hence the partial sum of RHS in $(1)$ telescopes to
$$
\sum_{n = k}^{m-1}\frac{C_{n}}{4^{n}}=\frac{2}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}-\frac{2}{4^{m}}\binom{2m}{m}.
$$

Hence
$$
\sum_{n = k}^\infty\frac{C_{n}}{4^{n}}=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n = k}^{m-1}\frac{C_{n}}{4^{n}}=\frac{2}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}.
$$

We have used $\frac{2}{4^{m}}\binom{2m}{m} \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$ which can be shown for example by the [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Asymptotic_growth), see also some other ways in [Determine $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{{n} \choose {\frac{n}{2}}}\frac{1}{2^n}$, where each $n$ is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288614).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, truly stunning.